# C++ constructors during function calls

Tags: c++, constructor, function-call

In C++ when you have an object that is passed to a function by value the copy constructor is invoked. Such as in this function signature:

```
void foo(Object o);
```

A couple years ago someone told me that you can pass arguments that fit the constructor of an object that is an argument to a function. So, using the above function signature foo, let's say Object has the constructor:

```
Object(int a, int b);
```

we would be able to call the function foo like this:

```
foo(1,2);
```

I haven't been able to find any information about this and I think that I either misinterpreted what I heard years ago or that the person was just wrong. Is there any way to do this other than:

```
foo(Object(1,2));
```

and if not, is there a reason that this constructor can not be implicitly invoked during a function call?

Comment: `foo( { 1, 2 } );`

Comment: ... provided that `Object`'s constructor is not explicit.

Comment: C++ does do implicit conversions using single value constructors that are not qualified with the 'explicit' keyword. [This was a helpful read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-mean)

Comment: @ConnorCrabtree this also applies to constructors with no or several parameters since C++11 (which brought uniform initialization).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A couple years ago someone told me that you can pass arguments that fit the constructor of an object that is an argument to a function.

If you recall it right, what was said is wrong.

Given your function and class, you may not use:

```
f(1, 2);
```

However, you may use:

```
f({1, 2});
```

The `{...}` will call an appropriate constructor, if one matches.

As a matter of personal preference, I would still use:

```
f(Object{1, 2});
```

IMO, the intent is more clearly expressed when using `Object{1, 2}` than when using just `{1, 2}`.